# How to distinguish per-user vs. system-wide installation in QT installer framework?

Tags: windows, qt, installation, qt-installer, pgmodeler

I'm using some app called pgModeler and it's current version provides an installer based on QT installer framework. The problem with that installer on Windows is that it installs [start menu entries per-user](https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler/issues/1350) only and [registers the app itself per-user](https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler/issues/1349) only as well. That's a problem for people like me using an explicit admin-user for system maintenance vs. a non-admin user for daily work. The important thing is that really two different user names are used (`Administrator` vs. `tschoening`) instead of Windows' default behaviour to restrict one user using UAC only.

Before switching to QT installer framework, Inno Setup has been used and that has some concept of [distinguishing between administrative and system-wide vs. per-user installation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=admininstallmode). The switch simply was to execute the installer as admin or not, everything else worked automatically and is not the case anymore with QT.

What I did find for QT as well are [pre-defined constants](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting.html#predefined-variables) to different paths e.g. for the start menu:

```
UserStartMenuProgramsPath
AllUsersStartMenuProgramsPath
```

What I did NOT find yet is if there's some automatic mode like Inno provided? Something like a simple setting telling the installer to prefer system-wide start menu and stuff always, really everything which the installer is able to distinguish. Or do developers need to build proper paths on their own? Like in the following example:

```
component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/pgmodeler.exe", "@StartMenuDir@/pgModeler.lnk"
```

vs.

```
component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/pgmodeler.exe", "@AllUsersStartMenuProgramsPath@/@StartMenuDir@/pgModeler.lnk"
```

In the case of the latter, how does one switch between per-user and system-wide `Programs and Features` in the control panel as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Found the following, which seems the answer to my question is that there's no concept like for Inno. But am still missing the `Programs and Features` part as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505642/qt-installer-framework-create-shortcut-in-start-menu-for-all-users?rq=1

Comment: Some people mention some `AllUsers`-setting supporting `true` and `false`, but can't find how that works anywhere. :-/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863638/qtifw-always-create-registry-entry

Answer (score 1):

Switching between installation for current and all users can be done using a setting called `AllUsers`, which supports `true` and `false`. The important things are where and when to provide that: One way is really early when invoking the installer using the following:

```
installer.exe AllUsers=true
```

That way the GUI to select a start menu group really already shows all entries available to all users, not only those of the user-private start menu, like has been before. Another way is [setting values on the installer at runtime](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#setValue-method). But it's important that this needs to happen BEFORE paths get resolved as well. An example can be seen at the following place:

```
function Controller()
{
    [...]
        //store all users and online/offline info
        installer.setValue("allUsers", isAdmin ? "true" : "false");
        installer.setValue("isOffline", installer.isOfflineOnly() ? "true" : "false");
    [...]
}
```

https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtIFW-Advanced-Setup/blob/master/installer/config/controller.js

These things have been enhanced in the past as well, even though I didn't find any explanation about what exactly and how to use it in the docs yet.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-124

Additionally, the software is not properly registered in `Programs and Features`, it only occurs admin-only:

[image: Programs and features Admin]
[image: Programs and features non-Admin]